# Using MOSI and MISO pins for multiple devices

Tags: arduino-nano, nrf24l01+, led-strip

For the device I am creating, I am hooking up an apa102 led strip to pins 11 and 13 to control each LED. But I would also like to hookup my NRF receiver to the arduino, but I also use pins 11 and 13. My question is can i hookup both to the same pins and control the inputs and outputs through the MOSI amd MISO pins separately!

Comment: Read about SPI. You can connect all devices to SCK, MISO, MOSI bus and address individual devices via CS(or SS).

Comment: @OlegMazurov the APA102 however doesn't have a CS pin, so it can't share a SPI bus. You can implement SPI in software (i.e. bitbang SPI).

Comment: @Gerben but you can disable the clock signal to the strip with a transistor or buffer, and it doesn't use the MISO at all so that's not an issue.